# How to add Tridion site in Internet Information Services(IIS) Manager?

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, tridion

I am working SDL TRIDION 2011 SP1 version. Suddenly I am unable to see the Trdion site in Internet Information Services(IIS) Manager.  Please tell me the procedure how to get it back again.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the correct IIS instance, on some 64 bit 2008 servers you will have two IIS consoles, one for IIS6 and one for IIS7, the SDL Tridion 2011 CME site will usually be in the IIS7 console. Options for getting it back would be to try a repair from the installer or a restore of your server backup (as obviously someone has deleted it if it is really gone)

Comment: @Bart Koopman Thank you for your response. I am sure I am looking at IIS7 only. I tried to repair the site stil I am not able to see the site(Repair is successful). Can you please tell me how to restore the server backup? For that should we already perform backup of site?

Comment: to restore the server backup you need to have created it before yes. If you have no backup of the server and the repair option fails then I'm afraid your best option would be to reinstall the CMS (uninstall and install again, you can make a backup copy of the configuration files to not have to redo the entire configuration in case you have a lot of changes in there).

Comment: @Bart Koopman Thank you for your valuable suggestions. In case If I run Content Manager installer in Modify mode. What are the consequences I can expect?

Comment: @Murali - you may want to consider committing to the Tridion SE site - A lot of these question would be appropriate there: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=eo63snjNlUWNn9xqeeO2NA2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @bart suggested, your best option to get the web application back (assuming it really has gone), is to run the repair option with the installer. There are a lot of folder specific settings which would be very hard to recreate manually.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried to add manually all the folders. But I am getting the blank page only. Please suggest me a way to get the site back. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try running the repair option of the installer?

Comment: Yes I tried running repair option of installer. The repair is successful, but I am not able to see the site.

Comment: Then perhaps try running it in modify mode. You may need to a remove and add the Content Manager Explorer in two runs of the installer. I would consider rebooting your server first though (just to make sure there is nothing odd stopping IIS showing it correctly).

Comment: In that case can I loose the existing data in the site?

Comment: Well I am not sure what data you are talking about. All of the content is stored in the database. If you have made any manual changes inside the ../Tridion/web folder of you install you should back those up first.

Comment: I tried to open webdav and checked all the data like schemas/components are present. If I run Installer in modify mode will it effect the data loss? And please provide the installation steps if you know. I am new to Tridion environment that is why I am asking all these things in detail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: WebDAV uses IIS, so if you can see something using WebDAV, your IIS instance is working. The Schemas and Components etc. are all in the database. They're not stored in the CME in IIS, so that will not be impacted if you just remove/install the CME.

Comment: Please provide steps to run installer in Modify mode and consequences if you know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know how to be any clearer. Either be specific about the data you are talking about, or understand that the CME is a gui that just accesses all of the data in the CM database. If you are really worried, install a new server and point it at your current DB and you will user all of you existing tridionPublication on the new server instance.

Comment: Ok, I will try for that. Can you please tell me how to connect to the existing database and fetch the data? As I am getting a blank Tridion page(I did manual creation of a website in IIS by cross verifying other server).

Comment: It sounds like you might benefit from attending an SDL Tridion Sys Admin training or hiring an SDL Tridion Infrastructure Consultant to help you grasp the basics. The database is configured using the Tridion MMC snap in, if you are doing a clean install you will be prompted for which database to use.

Comment: Thankyou I will try for reinstallation/Modifying the existing CME.

Comment: Thanks alot. Its great suggestion. I tried running the installer in Modify mode, it was successful. I am very happy to say all the things are working fine. Thanks alot again. :)

Answer (score 3):

Remove Tridion Completely (uninstall), then run the installer again.

You won't loose any data (it's all in the database), and you're likely to get your server up and running way faster than trying to fix by hand.